# Multiple Column Family with PutRequest

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, flume

I'm in process of writing a custom HbaseSink for use with Flume-NG 1.3.0, and need to perform a `org.hbase.async.PutRequest` with multiple column families in the same row. I do not see a constructor or anything similar to `Put.add(columnFamily, columnName, value)`.

Can someone shine some light on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: My current thought is to just split this into two requests... just wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to find the solution for this problem but could not find any reference. So here is what I did in my application

`

```
public void addRecord(String tableName, String rowKey, String family, HashMap<String, String> hash) {
        try {
            HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));

            Iterator<String> it = hash.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                String val = hash.get(key);
                put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(key), Bytes.toBytes(val));
            }
            table.put(put);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`

Here, the HashMap hash contains the column name and its value.